# Is there any direct command to install pyopenpose?

Tags: python

I am trying to use Openpose from windows and i need to run .py file. But i couldn't find any command to install pyopenpose module So where can I find pyopenpose module?

I tried this command on cmd:

```
C:\openpose\examples\tutorial_api_python>python 01_body_from_image.py
```

I get the error :

```
Error: OpenPose library could not be found. Did you enable `BUILD_PYTHON` in CMake and have this Python script in the right folder?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "01_body_from_image.py", line 26, in <module>
    raise e
  File "01_body_from_image.py", line 17, in <module>
    import pyopenpose as op
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyopenpose'
```

Comment: I have found the solution . I followed [python_module](https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/blob/master/doc/modules/python_module.md) compatibility options. I made sure that i checked `BUILD_PYTHON` in cmake-gui. And most  importantly i have to compile whole solution . I mean `OpenPose.sln` file must be compiled by clicking `Build Solution`. Whole solution can't be compiled by pressing `F5` or clicking the green play button.

Comment: Hello. I have got the same error,but I don't know how to fix that. can someone gave a look at this : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/166033/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pyopenpose-when-i-try-to-install-the-addo

Answer (score 2):

The error in general is that PyOpenPose cannot be found (an error similar to: ImportError: cannot import name pyopenpose). Ensure first that `BUILD_PYTHON` flag is set to `ON`. If the error persists, check the following:

In the script you are running, check for the following line, and run the following command in the same location as where the file is.

#### Ubuntu/OSX:

```py
sys.path.append('../../python');
```

```sh
ls ../../python/openpose
```

Check the contents of this location. It should contain one of the following files:

- `pyopenpose.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`
- `pyopenpose.so`

If you do not have any one of those, you may not have compiled openpose successfully, or you may be running the examples, not from the build folder but the source folder. If you have the first one, you have compiled PyOpenPose for Python 3, and have to run the scripts with `python3`, and vice versa for the 2nd one. Follow the testing examples above for exact commands.

#### Windows:

**Problem 1:** If you are in Windows, and you fail to install the required third party Python libraries, it might print an error similar to: Exception: Error: OpenPose library could not be found. Did you enable `BUILD_PYTHON` in CMake and have this Python script in the right folder?. From GitHub issue #941:

I had a similar issue with Visual Studio (VS). I am pretty sure that the issue is that while you are compiling OpenPose in VS, it tries to import cv2 (python-opencv) and it fails. So make sure that if you open cmd.exe and run Python, you can actually import cv2 without errors. I could not, but I had cv2 installed in a IPython environment (Anaconda), so I activated that environment, and then ran (change this to adapt it to your VS version and location of OpenPose.sln):

- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild.exe`
- `C:\path\to\OpenPose.sln`

**Problem 2:** Python for Openpose needs to be compiled in Release mode for now. This can be done in Visual Studio. Once that is done check this line:

```py
sys.path.append(dir_path + '/../../python/openpose/Release');
```

```
dir ../../python/openpose/Release
```

Check the contents of this location. It should contain one of the following files:

- `pyopenpose.cp36-win_amd64.pyd`
- `pyopenpose.pyd`

If such a folder does not exist, you need to compile in Release mode as seen above. If you have the first one, you have compiled PyOpenPose for Python 3, and have to run the scripts with `python3`, and vice versa for the 2nd one. Follow the testing examples above for exact commands. If that still does not work, check this line:

```py
os.environ['PATH'] = os.environ['PATH'] + ';' + dir_path + '/../../x64/Release;' + dir_path + '/../../bin;'
```

```
dir ../../x64/Release
dir ../../bin
```

Ensure that both of these paths exist, as PyOpenPose needs to reference those libraries. If they don't exist, change the path so that they point to the correct location in your build folder.

Comment: Can you please help me to know how to enable BUILD_PYTHON in CMake. As I'm new in CMake and need it badly!