# enable BUILD_PYTHON in CMake

Tags: python-3.x, github, cmake, openpose

I was trying to use Openpose from windows using https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose. But while I run a .py file it returned an error message

```
Error: OpenPose library could not be found. Did you enable `BUILD_PYTHON` in CMake and have this Python script in the right folder?
No module named 'pyopenpose'
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Santanu\Desktop\openpose\python\01_body_from_image.py", line 19, in <module>
    raise e

  File "C:\Users\Santanu\Desktop\openpose\python\01_body_from_image.py", line 16, in <module>
    import pyopenpose as op

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyopenpose'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SystemExit: -1
```

It has suggested from the error text to enable `'BUILD_PYTHON'` in `CMake` and also said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58318479/is-there-any-direct-command-to-install-pyopenpose/64175467). But I have never used CMake before. How to enable `'BUILD_PYTHON'` in `CMake`?

Comment: About enabling `BUILD_PYTHON` option see their documentation for building OpenPose: https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/blob/master/doc/installation/0_index.md#compiling-and-running-openpose-from-source